# On the product page how would I display an attributes text value based on the value of another attribute?

Tags: magento-1, frontend, custom-attributes

I am looking to use one attributes value to display another attributes value. 
 For example I would like the text value that is in `attribute_weight` to be displayed on the product page if `attribute_group` value is supersize.

I have the value in `attribute_weight` displayed, but it is all the time, I only want it to display if the `attribute_group` value is specifically supersized.

Here is the current code that has the weight attribute displaying on the product page for the associated products of configurables:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$prodWeight = $product->getData('weight');
$formattedWeight = Mage::helper('core')->getExactDivision($prodWeight, true, false);
if ($prodWeight) {
    echo 'Shipping Weight: <span class="price">'.$prodWeight.' lbs</span>'; 
}
```

Comment: Please add some code, where you want to display it.

Comment: I have it displaying properly on the product page in the location that I want it.. I am just missing the conditional statement if attribute_group = supersize then display the attribute_weight value...

Comment: It depends bit on your theme ;) Magento 1 or 2? Some code would be helpful.

Comment: Magento 1 using the Ultimo Theme.   Here is the current code that has the weight attribute displaying on the product page for the associated products of configurables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if ($product->getData('attribute_group') == 'supersize') {
    echo $product->getData('attribute_weight');
}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you!!  I am getting closer..  It's still not recognizing to pull in the attribute_weight.  I am getting the No Fees messaging, although the attribute_group is supersized

Comment: Check you attribute settings in backend ... Catalog - Manage Attributes: "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end"

Comment: I got it!  Thank you.  I had to change:  if ($product->getData('attribute_group') == 'supersize') to be: if ($product->getData('attribute_group') == '6225')